# Using jQuery slide to toggle between menu items

Tags: jquery, html, css

My goal is to make a menu comprised of three top-level categories, noted in the code as the three #fliptabs. When the user clicks on one fliptab, I'd like the corresponding pull-down panel to appear below. I've attempted to do this using jQuery slideDown. The issues I'm now struggling with in my current jsbin state below is enabling the user to be able to toggle between each of the top level categories (#fliptab) to view each pull-down (#panel) separately.

Here's what I've got so far: http://jsbin.com/iGOfowO/6/

For clarity, here is the same issue re-framed as more specific questions:
 - How do I enable the ability to switch from one top-level category's pull-down menu to another while showing only the selected top-level category's pull-down?
 - How do I feature a default toggled state? (I'd like #fliptabA to be displayed initially when a user has not yet clicked anything)

Any feedback would be very helpful as I'm very new to using HTML, CSS and jQuery. Thanks so much!

Comment: You could use jQuery Tabs. http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: @ariel thanks for the suggestion and link - this seems like a really clean and simple solution for what I'm trying to accomplish. I don't know why it didn't occur to me to simply use the search term 'tabs'. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way but should work: http://jsbin.com/INEkimIt/1/edit?html,css,js,output you should take a look to some jquery plugins as suggested above